# Obtaining a pointer to a class method so that it can be passed as a callback to a C function

Tags: objective-c, c, function-pointers, libssh2

I'm using libssh2 and have a callback function defined outside my SSHWrapper object:

```
static void kbd_callback(const char *name, int name_len, const char *instruction, int instruction_len, int num_prompts, const LIBSSH2_USERAUTH_KBDINT_PROMPT *prompts, LIBSSH2_USERAUTH_KBDINT_RESPONSE *responses, void **abstract);
```

From within my SSHWrapper object I do the following, passing the callback function when authenticaing the session:

```
/* Create a session instance */
LIBSSH2_SESSION *session = libssh2_session_init_ex(NULL, NULL, NULL, self);
while ((rc = libssh2_userauth_keyboard_interactive(session, userChar, &kbd_callback)) == LIBSSH2_ERROR_EAGAIN);
```

What I'm wondering is, is it possible to move the `kbd_callback()` function inside my object, so that it's a class method: `+(void) kbd_callback:...`?

If so, how do I get the address of that function in order to pass it to the C function `libssh2_userauth_keyboard_interactive()`?

Comment: Ok to sum everything up am I correct in saying the following:  In this specific case, using IMP will not work. IMPs can be used in other cases where you need a c-style function pointer that has less strict signature requirements?

Comment: I think that's a good summary, yes. I would add that the approach you've already taken is what I do when integrating a C-style library with an Objective-C program.

Comment: cool, thanks and thanks everyone else for the help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The approach you're taking now is reasonable. That said, Objective-C methods are in fact just C functions. The main thing complicating the approach you suggest is that they include two "hidden" arguments, `self`, and `_cmd`. `self` is the instance of the object the method is being called on, and `_cmd` is the selector  for the method. You can't change these and their presence will make it impossible to make your function's arguments match those required for the callback function.

Just in case it's still interesting to you, you can get a function pointer to an Objective-C method like so:

```
IMP methodIMP = [self methodForSelector:@selector(someMethodThatTakesOneStringArgument:)];
void (*functionPointer)(id, SEL, NSString*) = (void (*)(id, SEL, NSString*))methodIMP;

// Then call it:
functionPointer(instance, @selector(someMethodThatTakesOneStringArgument:), aString);
```

EDIT: I posted a simple, complete program that demonstrates this code in action here: https://gist.github.com/2731937

Comment: +1. Since OP asked about a class method, I'll point out that for those `self` is the class object (i.e. `[SSHWrapper class]`).

Comment: Thanks Ken. The fact that the OP mentioned a class method slipped my attention.

Comment: While I'm nitpicking, I'll mention that your cast doesn't help if the type of `functionPointer` is still just `IMP`. You need to properly type that as well as do the cast.

Comment: Thanks Ken, it's fixed. That's what I get for typing code off the top of my head...

Answer (score -1):

No. The underlying C function that gets created by `+ (void)method` should not be called directly in this fashion. Unless you are very familiar with the underlying Objective-C runtime, messing with the IMP functions will only get you into trouble.

Comment: I disagree. There's nothing all that dangerous about IMPs. You do have to cast them to the right function pointer type to match the method's arguments and return type, but that's really it.

Comment: In this example, it will not work. In the more general case, bypassing the message passing system can result in different behavior. I wouldn't recommend it for novice Objective-C developers that aren't familiar with how message get passed.